# How to Return The Address of String(As Char Pointer)

Tags: c, arrays, string, 2d, return-type

My file include just 1 word (max 20 character) in every line and it has 100 line also.I am trying to read random line from file,and  put it in char *str this random string.I need the address of the word to use the string read later(because after i will print it in 2d array (like word puzzle).
How should I return their address or what is needed to print it in different function late?Could you show me one example about that,ı am searching it about 1 day read random word from file and still not enlightened.

```
char read(char *file, char *str);
return (char *)str;
```

is not working as I expected there is warning which is

> *returning ‘char *’ from a function with return type ‘char’ makes integer from pointer without a cast.*

Comment: WHY ARE YOU SHOUTING?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, do not use the same name as library functions for user-defined functions, `read()` is a well-known POSIX library function.

That said, the error (or warning) message is quite clear, there's a type mismatch. To return a `char *`, you need to have a function with return type of `char *`. Define the function having `char *` as return type, like

```
char * my_read (.....
```

instead of

```
char my_read (.....
```

Comment: Thank you now ı got it .Is there any method except returning char pointer (like return just char array and using it's contents(string) in another function )